# How to open a URL in a new window in SSRS report?

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I want to open a PDF file in a new window by clicking on its URL in SSRS report. I heard that it is possible with JavaScript. So I tried with `="javascript:void window.open('yoururl&rs:Command=Render"')"` in the SSRS expression. It is working only for https and http.

But the URL which I want to open is as follows. `\\\ourcompanyname.local\systems\documents\abcd.pdf`.

As a database developer, I will be very happy if it is possible with SQL script. If not please help me with some JavaScript.

Comment: Can you post the value from your Action expression, please? You aren't including &rs:Command=Render are you? When it doesn't work, what happens, error/nothing? Are you testing this in BIDS, or from the reportserver (the javascript will not work in a BIDS preview)?

Comment: ="javascript:void(document.open('" & Fields!LOCATION.Value &"','_blank'))"
We are getting the pdf location(URL) from location column.
I am using this expression in jump to URL action. It is working for http and https websites. but not working for the URL in the format as \\ourcompanyname.local\systems\documents\abcd.pdf
Please let me know if I need to change the expression. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use target="_blank"

```
<a href="http://your path" target="_blank">test</a>
```

or

```
window.open( 'http://path');
```

Comment: Hi Prash. Thanks for your quick response. This code works with http and https. but my URL is some how different. \\ourcompanyname.local\systems\documents\abcd.pdf

Comment: I am a little confused here, the code you are using should work.  So l am wondering about the url you have provided as an example - \ourcompanyname.local\systems\documents\abcd.pdf.  What happens if you paste that url into a browser address window does it open the PDF?  If not then l would say the URL is the challenge.  What about the URL http://ourcompanyname.local/systems/documents/abcd.pdf (as suggested by prash).  What happens if you paste that URL into a browser address window?

Comment: Hi Bob,
Thank you very much. 
The URL which we are using in the format (starts with double back slash)\\ourcompanyname.local\systems\documents\abcd.pdf
Yes we are able to open this URL in browser.

Comment: Hi sorry only just seen your reply, if you are able to the PDF from your machine.  The syntax you provided is correct for the javascript.  Which makes me wonder if the URL that you supply can be addressed via a web server?  That is the URL does that resolve to an internal file server, as opposed to a valid web address.  Sorry out of my depth here so not sure of the correct term.